# Updating column value based on nan value of other column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array, nan

I have this simple function with 2 columns. What I'm trying to do is to check what group has a number of nan and change it to a new desired value.
Here's a code snippet:

```
def twod_array():
    data = {"group": [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3],
            'numbers': [[2], [14, 15], [16, 17], [19, 20, 21], [np.nan]],
            }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
    new_group_number = 100
    df.loc[4, "group"] = new_group_number
    return df
```

Before:
This is how the data looks like, you can assume numbers are sorted.

```
   group       numbers
0     -1           [2]
1      0      [14, 15]
2      1      [16, 17]
3      2  [19, 20, 21]
4      3         [nan]
```

In my example I know where nan and since it was at position 4, I was able to use loc to change it to a 100, like this:

```
   group       numbers
0     -1           [2]
1      0      [14, 15]
2      1      [16, 17]
3      2  [19, 20, 21]
4    100         [nan]
```

What if I don't know where the nan is? How can I know which group to update? All that comes to my mind is nested for loop which I would rather avoid... Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace

```
df.loc[4, "group"] = new_group_number
```

with

```
idx = df.numbers.apply(lambda l: any(pd.isna(e) for e in l))
df.loc[idx, 'group'] = new_group_number
```

Answer (score 0):

If np.nan could occur more than once then you can use:

```
df.loc[df['numbers'].apply(pd.isna).apply(any), 'group'] = 100
```

or

```
df.loc[df['numbers'].apply(lambda x: pd.isna(x).any()), 'group'] = 100
```

Or if you think there is only one np.nan then you could use `.isin` :

```
df.loc[df['numbers'].isin([[np.nan]]), 'group'] = 100
```

Comment: Does not work if a list has more than one (nan) element

Comment: Of course, but OP's data doesn't indicate that.

Comment: Fair enough; *what group has a number of nan* could mean either

Comment: Ok I edited my answer to accommodate multiple 'nan's in the list.